# How is MSE 5 years old?

Tags: support, meta, site-stats

If you look at [this page](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) Meta Stack Exchange is listed at being 5y5m old. However, [MSE was only introduced April 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/): 7m ago.

My theory is that when MSO was mirrored to become MSE, the creation date was never changed. I think this should be updated to reflect the accurate `7m` rather than `5y5m`.

Comment: Having questions asked 5 years ago in a site aged 7 months is quite confusing, don't you think?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Heh, that reminds me of early Programmers (when a significant amount of its content was migrations from SO, and finding questions and answers older than the site wasn't exactly rare).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the old date should be kept. MSE was more of a renaming than the creation of a new site, and the community reflects that.

MSE was formed by just renaming MSO, and the new MSO was started from scratch.